# ASP.NET C# Login CSS error

Tags: asp.net, css, authentication

I'm creating a Login page with C# ASP.net, After i apply this code

```
<system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

Then, my login page appear without CSS on it. then again I fix it by using

```
<location path="~/Styles/Site.css">
<system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    </location>
```

The css has return. Then the problem is that the login page is gone. It straight show the content of my website without need to login. It is logged in default by using my computer ID which is AZTECH\user. Anyone have solution for this help please. Appreciate much.

Comment: I hope you really have a `</location>` as end-node.

Answer (score 0):

What the  is doing is saying that you wish to ALLOW ANONYMOUS users access to everything.

Try this, for the first tag:

```
<system.web>
   <authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
   </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Then for the location, do:

```
<location path="~/styles/styles.css" >
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
<location path="~/images/" >
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
<location path="~/login.aspx" >
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Note, that I also added location tags for LOGIN as well as the Images folder. You may need to add additional tags as needed for javascript files and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried, The css still won't work properly...

then I put it the other way round which is;

```
 <location path="Manu.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>

<location path="Score.aspx">
            <system.web>
                <authorization>
                    <deny users="?"/>
                </authorization>
            </system.web>
        </location>
```

And all the other content that only able to view after login.